# How can i get the default options to show again after removing some? Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I implemented a button that has 2 options yes and no. If I change the option from yes to no my script will remove some options from another multioption field. But if I change the option field back to yes the options will stay removed. Is it possible to reset the optionfield with the removed options? Or do I have to add the options back manually with the addOption() methode?

I tried a lot of microsoft methodes already but there seems to be no for my usecase.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Before you remove your options, save them to a variable. Then you can easily add them back again.